# How can I show that $l^p$ has empty interior in $l^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Could maybe someone help me here?

> For $p\in [1,2)$ I need to show that $l^p$ has empty interior in $l^2$.

I know that I need to show that there is no open ball $B(y,r)=\{x\in l^2: ||x-y||_2<r\}$ in $l^p$ with $y\in l^2$ and $r>0$.

My Idea was to assume that there exists $y\in l^2$ and $r>0$ such that $B(y,r)\subset l^p$. Now I wanted to find $x\in B(y,r)$ s.t. $\sum_{n\geq 1} |x_n|^p=\infty$ because then I would get a contradiction.

Is there a possibility to find such an $x$ or do I need to start from another point?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $Y$ is a proper linear subspace of a normed space $X,$ then the interior of $Y$ is empty. Indeed if $Y$ contains a ball in $X,$ then by additivity it contains a ball in $X$ centered at $0.$  Hence by homogeneity it contains the whole space $X.$ In your case even
$$Y=\bigcup_{1\le p<2}\ell^p\subsetneq \ell^2=X$$ has empty interior. In particular every single $\ell^p$ for $1\le p<2$ has empty interior.

Answer (score 4):

By contradiction, if this interior was not empty, it would contain some point $y\in\ell^p$ and some $\ell^2$-ball $B(y,r)$ ($r>0$) around it. Let $z_n:=n^{-1/p},$ then $z\in\ell^2\setminus\ell^p,$ so that $x:=y+\frac r{2\|z\|_2}z\notin\ell^p.$ But $\|x-y\|_2<r,$ a contradiction.

Comment: but shouldn't I pick $y$ arbitrarily. So are you working with my idea from the question or not?

Comment: So I mean can't I pick $y\in l^2$ and $r>0$ and assume $B(y,r)\subset l^p$. But then I define $x=\left(1+\frac{r}{2||y||_2}\right)y$ then $||x-y||_2<r$ and $||x||_p=\infty$

Comment: ah okey so I can't fix this?

Comment: Fixed. Note that $y$ belongs to (the interior of) $\ell^p$ and not only to $\ell^2,$